# c3.js: possible to label x axis and multiple y axes?

Tags: charts, c3.js

Is it possible to define values for the X-axis values in a C3.js chart that also has multiple y values?

I am trying to create a mixed bar- and line- chart with two y-axes and custom labels for the x-axis.

The result should be something like this:

[desired-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKqC2.png)

I have referred to the C3.js examples to guide my attempts: c3js.org/samples/axes_y2.html and c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_values.html I am able to produce the mixed line and bar chart with 2 y-axes.  When I add the in labels to the x-axis, however, I lose the second y axis:

I can get the chart to show 2 y-axes:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
          x : 'x',
          columns: [
            ['x', 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
            ['open cases', 0, 7, 10, 12, 14, 19, 12, 17, 19, 18, 23, 24, 33, 42, 54, 63, 52, 51],
            ['total budget', 0, 1359300, 1700900, 2248200, 2417400, 2966846, 2966846, 2658700, 3009082, 3919996, 4212200, 4319972, 4882937, 5026751, 5671243, 5059538, 5896239, 6289674]
          ],
          axes: {
            'total budget': 'y2'
          },
          types: {
            'open cases': 'bar' // ADD
          }
        },
        axis: {
          y: {
            label: {
              text: 'open cases',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          },
          y2: {
            show: true,
            label: {
              text: 'total budget',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          }
        }
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

... but once I try to add labels for x-axis, the second y axis disappears:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
          x : 'x',
          columns: [
            ['x', 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
            ['open cases', 0, 7, 10, 12, 14, 19, 12, 17, 19, 18, 23, 24, 33, 42, 54, 63, 52, 51],
            ['total budget', 0, 1359300, 1700900, 2248200, 2417400, 2966846, 2966846, 2658700, 3009082, 3919996, 4212200, 4319972, 4882937, 5026751, 5671243, 5059538, 5896239, 6289674]
          ],
          axes: {
            'total budget': 'y2'
          },
          types: {
            'open cases': 'bar' // ADD
          }
        },
        axis: {
          y: {
            label: {
              text: 'open cases',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          },
          y2: {
            show: true,
            label: {
              text: 'total budget',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    values: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
                },
            }
        }
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvsdvh8w/3/

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of C3.js?  Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge and insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a trivial syntax error you'll kick yourself for ;-)

You've declared `axis` twice in the configuration above

Instead, put the x axis declaration in the axis property alongside the y axes

```
axis: {
          y: {
            label: {
              text: 'open cases',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          },
          y2: {
            show: true,
            label: {
              text: 'total budget',
              position: 'outer-middle'
            }
          }
        },
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                    values: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
                },
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvsdvh8w/4/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What about more than two additional Y axis? Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think so in C3 Daniel, max is 2. If you have multiple data series at different scales you could normalise the values somehow to the same scale if you want see possible correlations between them